# Exclude request with get parameter from .htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess

I have this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ script.php
```

It redirects all image requests to `script.php`. I'd like to exclude all requests that contain GET parameter, for example `http://myweb.com/image.jpg?process=0` but have `http://myweb.com/image.jpg` included.

How should I edit my rule? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should test on the `%{QUERY_STRING}` if does contain something :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ script.php
```